# Лишнее уже в уведомлении о переносе комментариев

Tags: дефект, локализация, инструменты-модератора

[Обработал](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1011963/178988) тревогу переносом всех комментариев в чат и получил вот такое сообщение:

> [image: скриншот]

Слово "уже" тут явно лишнее:

> Все комментарии уже скопированы в чат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/7674

Поменял на:

> Все комментарии скопированы в чат.